# How to know if an environment variable was inherited from parent process?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

Consider a process running in the PID 100 (it can be an ordinary shell command line). So, we launch a program (`fork()/exec()`) which starts to run in the PID 101. Now our playground is ready:

The program running in the PID 101 exports some environment variables, and do an `exec()` in a second program, Then, it starts to run in the same PID 101 ("environment").

How can this second program know if a certain environment variable was exported from the parent PID 100 or was defined by the predecessor program running in the "reused" current PID ?

Comment: Environment is just a set of key-value pairs. It carries no other information.

Answer (score 2):

> How can this second program know if a certain environment variable was exported 
>   from the parent PID 100 or was defined by the predecessor program running in the "reused" current PID ?

There's no way differentiate that (unless the variables themselves contain some additional information -- such as prefix/suffix in their names or values, etc).

As far as, PID 101 is concerned every environment variable is from its *parent* (a process has only one parent) and it doesn't care and can't know if it's from PID 100 or from the parent of PID 100 or some other process leading upto the exec of PID 101.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare environment of 101 with the original environment of father
`/bin/env`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there are no ways to do that, but I used the following workaround:

The first process exports a variable with its `realpath` and PID. So, when in the same PID but different executable path I assume the variable was inherited, when in the same PID and exe path, I assume that it's in the process (program) that created the variables.

I know it isn't unfailing. There are no warranties that the PID and `realpath` will assure if the variables are inherited or no. But, is working.